# How to define the line-breaker in css(HTML)

Tags: html, css

I created a dotted-line frame, it works fine.
However, I need to fine the line-breaker like the tag

```
<pre class="code"'>
```

Here is an example
[image]

The tag span does not work in my dottedline frame ... is there a way to implement the line breaker?

I have may pages using the tag

```
<pre class="code"'>
```

I just wanted to replace them with my dotted-line frame.   I know that the tag `<br>` works, but it needs lots of works to modify ...

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you would like each `span` to be on its own line?

Comment: You need to read up on block vs inline elements https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_blocks.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```css
.dashed2 span {
  display: block;
}
```

You could also add a line break (`<br>`) to your html, but it is better practice to style in css